# EditText with hint, where hint moves

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-edittext

I have seen `EditText` that has a hint and when user taps on it the hint moves up reducing the font size and making the field editable by the user. When the user moves to another `EditText` leaving it blank the hint appears back in full size.

What is it and how can I add it in my activity on Android Studio using XML?

I am on Android Studio using Kotlin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you mean this

[image]

it is [TextInputLayout](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)

Add the dependency for the design support library inside the `build.gradle` (Module: app) file as shown below.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
```

the latest version at this time is `1.2.0-alpha03` you can see latest version from [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material)

Then, you can use it like this in your xml layouts.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/myTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/my_editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/YOUR_HINT"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDarkestGray" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. However, for a beginner like me this code is not enough as you have not mentioned to add the dependency, though the XML code is perfect. I can choose this as the answer if the dependency part is added to your reply.

Comment: @user3765415 i have added the dependency

Comment: OK. Your code work perfect when I add it as it is, but when I move add constraints it does not work as expected. I gave same margin to both components. can you check what went wrong?

Comment: i think this is another question !

Comment: No, this is not useful otherwise.

Comment: I fixed it, I have to give margin only for one element and not for both.

Answer (score 0):

This is `TextInputLayout` and you can use `editText` as child in it like this :

**At first** add the dependency for the design support library inside the `build.gradle` file as shown below.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

And if you are using `AndroidX` use this :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

**Second** ,Then implement that like this :

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Floating Hint Enabled Default" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Android `TextInputLayout` Features**

```
1-Enabling/Disabling floating hints

2-Enabling/Disabling floating hint animation

3-Displaying Error Messages

4-Showing Character Counter

5-Password Visibility Toggle and . . .
```

Comment: I added dependency, and it throws error when I sync. I tried the first one and when it threw error I tried the second one too. Both threw error when sync. Note: I did not add XML.

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3 s 123 ms)


NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

Comment: Add it in build.gradle(module:app) in dependencies{} block , we have two build.gradle add it in right place

Comment: And in your build.gradle(project:yourproject) in allprojects->repositories block add these :         google(),  jcenter() ,     maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }

Comment: That fixed the error, however, when I add the XML code it throws some error. I will add that as a separate comment.Where I added the XML code ( as it is) that you provided is before starting the code for Buttons and EditTexts that is already there.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\A\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_lost_item.xml:10: AAPT: error: resource dimen/activity_horizontal_margin (aka com.example.lostandfound:dimen/activity_horizontal_margin) not found.

Comment: Please fix your dimens in XML activity

Comment: Why is it saying 'This operation requires the library com.android.support:design:+. Would you like to add this now?' every time I move it in the design layout.
I click 'OK', but again it show the same message when I move it.

Comment: Use implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1' because you dont use AndroidX , but update it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205850/discussion-between-user3765415-and-milad-salimi).